# I want to save a file to a network hard drive from a Docker Compose, running on a Linux MiniPC

Tags: docker-compose, network-drive, mounted-volumes, home-assistant

I have installed a camera at the door of my house (Reolink doorbell POE).
I have it integrated into Home Assistant with Docker Compose running on a PC.
I want it to record when it detects movement and save the file to a network drive.
I have gotten it to record on the PC, but I can't get it to record on the network hard drive.

I detail the steps I have taken and how far I have come, but I have not achieved it yet.

- The path of my hard drive is: `\\192.168.1.5\Camara`
  It is a local and public folder, so it does not require a username or password.
- Home Assistant is in the directory: `home/casa/docker/homeassistant`

  - User: home
  - Password: 1234  (I detail them as an example to describe it better)

I have **mounted a network share** (a network hard drive) in a local directory: `~/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camara`
For that, first, from the Home Assistant directory, I have created the directory for mounting `/mnt/camera` in the Home Assistant directory within the host file system using the command: `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/camera`.

Then I have already **mounted the network disk** in the mount directory, using the command:
`sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.5/Camara ~/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camara -o username=casa,password=1234`
This told me Allows access to the network disk from within the Home Assistant container.
If I run in terminal: `ls -l ~/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camera` to see what is in the folder, it goes directly to the hard drive and I see its contents, so it directs correctly.
If I create a file with: `sudo touch ~/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camara/test4.txt` It creates it and I can see it on the hard drive.

I have modified the **docker-compose.yaml** to mount the mount directory in the Home Assistant container.

```
volumes:
      - './config:/config'
      - ~/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camara:/Camara:rw
```

I **restarted the Home Assistant container** for the configuration changes to take effect.

In my first test, to start recording on the PC hard drive, I wrote on the Home Assistant automation:

```
data:
      filename: /media/camera/filename.mp4
```

Now, to try to record on the hard drive, I indicate the new address:

```
data:
      filename: /mnt/camera/filename.mp4
```

I have tried different paths in that file description:

```
filename: /mnt/camera/filename.mp4
filename: ~/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camera /filename.mp4
filename: /home/casa/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camera/filename.mp4
```

But it hasn't worked with any of them and it always gave me the error:
`Can't write /home/casa/docker/homeassistant/mnt/camera/filename.mp4, no access to path!`

I have something left to do, but I can't locate what it is or where the error is. I really appreciate if anyone can help me.